# Como selecionar valor de uma lista dropbox quando o html do site não tem select

Tags: python

Olá!

Primeiramente, desculpe meu vocabulário pouco 'técnico', sou apenas um aventureiro iniciando a aprendizagem em Python.

Em relação ao meu problema, eu já vi alguns tópicos tanto aqui quanto em inglês porém todos tratam de uma maneira semelhante, como essa:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('url')

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('fruits01'))

# select by visible text
select.select_by_visible_text('Banana')

# select by value 
select.select_by_value('1')
```

Porém, quando tento aplicar isso no site que desejo, o dropbox list dele não é feito com select no html dele, então da erro dizendo que não consegue usar esse comando para essa situação.

Eu consigo clicar no botão com o xpath dele, que abre a lista com todos valores (de 1 a 90 - 'minutos de um jogo de futebol'), porém não consigo selecionar nenhum desses itens. Cada uns desses valores da lista mudam as saídas da página, como placar, chutes a gol, etc.

Quando eu inspeciono os valores do botão, os valores deles estão lá embaixo do html, porém não os encontro nem com o xpath, da erro na compilação dizendo que não encontra, mesmo que eu clique nele com um time.sleep() para carregar a página ele não encontra.

O trecho do html do botão está nessas imagens:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E as opções vão até o número 90, como dito acima.

Tem alguma forma de clicar em um item dessa lista, sem ser pelo comando select? Ou há alguma forma de usar o select mesmo nesse site?

Já consegui descobrir diversas coisas novas olhando fóruns porém esse realmente me travou nos últimos dois dias e continuo sem solução.

Agradeço desde já e caso queiram mais alguma informação, só me dizer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente consegui resolver

Caso alguém algum dia tenha esse problema também, segue a solução que encontrei fuçando em todo quanto é tipo de site/foruns de python:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

droplist = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="root"]/div/section/section/main/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div' ))) #encontrar botao da droplist (nesse caso achei melhor com xpath, site mal montado)
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(droplist)
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', droplist)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'li.ant-select-dropdown-menu-item')))

drop_down_click = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//li [text()="20"]')))
drop_down_click.click()
```

Isso seguindo o HLTM do site que postei em imagens, para selecionar o minuto 20 de um jogo, mas poderia ser qualquer texto dessa droplist do combobox que não era montado com select no html. Na segunda imagem postada estão as opções dessa droplist, do 1 ao 90... no caso acima ele selecionaria o minuto 20. Só postei o trecho do programa dessa solução em específico.